# datatables, change results from SSI

Tags: datatables

i use the SSI-Solution from the datatables-examples.

Now, i want to change and edit some results of the database (for example, i want to change a stored id throug an icon for this id etc.).

For the moment i have no idear at wich point i can catch the results and work with them. Maybe someone can explain it for me.

Here is the code if use for getting the database results

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'MODUL_1_CONTACTS';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'ACCOUNT_ID';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'CONTACT_GROUP',   'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'KD_NO',           'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'TYPE',      'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'ORG_NAME',  'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'VORNAME',   'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'NAME',      'dt' => 5 )
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */
require( $vz.'assets/global/plugins/datatables/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

Here is the JS Code

```
var table = $('#ajax_table1').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
        url: 'data.php',
        pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
    } ),
    "columnDefs": [                      
        {
          "targets": -1,
          "data": null,
          "defaultContent": "<button class=\"btn yellow-mint uppercase btn-circle\" data-toggle=\"confirmation\" id=\"bs_confirmation_demo_1\">Confirmation 1</button><div class=\"btn-group pull-right\"><button class=\"btn green btn-xs btn-outline dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Tools<i class=\"fa fa-angle-down\"></i></button><ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\"><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i> delete </a></li><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-text\"></i> write letter </a></li><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-calendar-plus-ot\"></i> new todo/date </a></li><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-cubes\"></i> new work </a></li><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-print\"></i> Print </a></li><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-pdf-o\"></i> Save as PDF </a></li><li><a href=\"javascript:;\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-excel-o\"></i> Export to Excel </a></li></ul></div>"
     }],
    "language": {
           url: '../lang/<?php echo $_GET['lang'].'/'.$_GET['lang']; ?>.json'
     },
    // setup buttons extentension: http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/
    buttons: [
            { extend: 'print', className: 'btn dark btn-outline' },
            { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn green btn-outline' },
            { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn purple btn-outline' }
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
    ],
    //responsive: true,
    "bFilter": true,
    // set the initial value
    "pageLength": 10,
    //Layout
    "dom": "<'pull-left'f><'pull-right' B>r<'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'>>",

} );
```

Comment: _i want to change a stored id throug an icon for this id_ makes no sense.  Can you explain it a bit better please?

Comment: it was only one example, i must work with the datas from the database a lot more, before they finaley show in the datatables, so i have to know how i can catched this datas...

Comment: OK, it sounds like you need to manipulate or format the data before you display it.  Can you post your datatables javascript code?

Comment: i've update the code with the js-scriptcode Is there any way to catch the results from the database in the php file?

Comment: I thought this question was about datatables, not php.